# TypeError: Cannot read property 'extendedProps' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to set the tooltip but get error

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


  header:{
   left:'prev,next today',
   center:'title',
   right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
   eventRender: function(info) {
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    },

  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  editable:false,
  locale: 'sl',
  navLinks: true,   
  events: 'load.php',
  selectable:false,
  selectHelper:false,
  displayEventTime: false



 });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info.event is undefined which is why you cannot read property "extendedProps."

To protect yourself from undefined objects, I would use the pattern:

```
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: ((info.event || {}).extendedProps || {}).description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
```

I would do a console.log(info) right before you initialize var tooltip to figure out what "info" actually is.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that `info.event` is equal to `undefined`. I'd recommend that you try to `console.log(info)` or use the debugger and see what the value of `info` is that is being passed into that function before you try to access `info.event.extendedProps`.